# Caption package with beamer changing tables to figures

Tags: beamer, captions

I have a weird problem Whenever I use the caption package with beamer class on Mac OS (Windows works fine), Tables labels are changed to Figures (only started happening recently) .. I wonder what could be the problem.

See preamble of my latex presentation:

```
\documentclass[english,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter

\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
% this default might be overridden by plain title style
\newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
% (ERT) argument for the TOC
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
  \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
  \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%\usetheme{Warsaw}
% or ...
%\usetheme{Madrid}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.2 cm}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{latexsym}
%\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{: } 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-network}

\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{diagbox}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
% or whatever (possibly just delete it)
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}
%\usepackage{float}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\algsetup{linenosize=\small}


\renewcommand{\makebeamertitle}
{
\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\frame{\titlepage}
\endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title[]{Example}
\author[latex forum]{example\and \\ \bigskip{}
}
\institute[]{%\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{institution-logo-filename} \\\\
}
\date[October 2019]{}

\makebeamertitle

%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}



\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{CIs Disruptions Examples}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular*}{12cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
\toprule 
Date & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Disruption}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
{\scriptsize{}November 1965} & {\scriptsize{}Blackout in ten states in the northeastern US affected
30 million people.}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
{\scriptsize{}July 1977} & {\scriptsize{}In New York’s suburbs,10 million people to lose power
for over 24 h.}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
{\scriptsize{}December 1978} & {\scriptsize{}Blackout in part of France due to voltage collapse.}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
{\scriptsize{}January 1981} & {\scriptsize{}1.5 million customers in Idaho, Utah, and Wyoming were
affected for 7 h.}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
{\scriptsize{}March 1982} & {\scriptsize{}Over 900 000 lost power for 1.5 h due to high-voltage
line failure in Oregon.}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
{\scriptsize{}December 1994} & {\scriptsize{}2 million customers from Arizona to Washington State
lost power.}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
{\scriptsize{}July 1996} & {\scriptsize{}Blackouts for 2 million customers in 14 states for approximately
6h.}\tabularnewline
\midrule 
{\scriptsize{}August 2003} & {\scriptsize{}Northeastern United States and Canada cascading outages}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{\label{tab:Disruptions-Examples}Power Disruptions Examples}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
%

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: \@captype is figure from the very start, so somehow \table was clobbered.

Comment: I am not following .. on windows, the same latex file produces Table 1 instead of Figure 1

Comment: As a quick fix, you can use `\begin{table}\expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{table}`.

Comment: Actually, `\begin{table}\relax` will fix it.  Is Beamer's version of `\table` expecting an argument?

Comment: BTW, you table of contents mod is backwards:  \gobbletableofcontents should come first, assuming you want of remove the optional argument.

Comment: The quick fix has worked but \relax didn't .. how can I make the fix for all tables without adding code for each table

Comment: I would fix the problem by editing the line in caption.sty Ulrike has highlighted in her answer, i.e. replacing `\figure` with `\table` in that line. (Usually it's not a good idea at all to edit LaTeX package files, but in this case it's IMHO a practical work-around until a new version of the `caption` package containing the bug fix will overwrite the file caption.sty anyway.) (I will release a new version within the next days.)

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a clear bug. The code sets the code for the table to figure:

```
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{%
  \caption@InfoNoLine{beamer document class}%
  \let\caption@ORI@figure\figure
  \def\figure{\caption@settype{figure}\caption@ORI@figure}
  \let\caption@ORI@table\figure %<------------------------HERE
  \def\table{\caption@settype{table}\caption@ORI@table}
}{}
```

Report it to the maintainer.

Comment: What a stupid bug :-(

Comment: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/commit/18336d5f5ef245683d812fc77084e879da763412

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt this just came up again: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/517287/2388

Comment: A fixed version of the `caption` package is available on CTAN and will hopefully soon find its way into MikTeX and TeXlive.

Answer (score 1):

Beamer's version of table must be getting replaced by the caption package.  Simply restore it after caption is loaded using

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}[1][]{%
  \def\@captype{table}%
  \par\nobreak\begin{center}\nobreak}
  {\par\nobreak\end{center}\nobreak}
\makeatother
```

Alternatively, one can save and restore table using:

```
\let\beamertable=\table
\let\beamerendtable=\endtable
\usepackage{caption}
\let\table=\beamertable
\let\endtable=\beamerendtable
```