# Table caption starts with Figure after using the caption package

Tags: captions

It is pretty weird that once I load the `caption` package, all table captions start with "Figure", instead of "Table".

For example,

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\begin{table}   
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{c}
a \\        
b \\    
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

produces
[image]

Yet, removing the `caption` package solves the problem.

It seems that the problem exists only for new versions of the `caption` package. For example, on my office computer, where the `caption` packages was installed on September 2018, the problem disappear, but on my personal laptop, which generates the problem above, the package was installed a few months ago.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! With your MWE I cant reproduce your problem! Caption label is `Table` (as expected).

Comment: I get the problem too.  Beamer is dated 10/4/2019 and caption is dated 9/8/2019 (MikTeX).  \tablename is still Table.

Comment: Until they get the bug fixed, use \captionof{table}{...}.

Comment: \@captype in table is set to figure, but only when using the caption package.

Comment: hm, I have recent MikTeX installation (hopefully with recent version of `caption` and `beamer`). I wonder, why you like to use `caption` package? `beamer` offer good own support for managing caption style.

Comment: This is already known to the maintainer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512771/2388

Comment: A fixed version of the `caption` package is available on CTAN and will hopefully soon find its way into MikTeX and TeXlive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the following in caption.sty:

```
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{%
  \caption@InfoNoLine{beamer document class}%
  \let\caption@ORI@figure\figure
  \def\figure{\caption@settype{figure}\caption@ORI@figure}
  \let\caption@ORI@table\figure
  \def\table{\caption@settype{table}\caption@ORI@table}
}{}
```

which sets `\@captype` to table, then resets it to figure.
Anyway, one can avoid the problem using:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer} 
\let\BeamerFigure=\figure
\let\BeamerTable=\table
\usepackage{caption}
\let\figure=\BeamerFigure
\let\table=\BeamerTable
\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\begin{table}
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{c}
a \\        
b \\    
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!