# LaTeX: problem with table captions when using the subfig pagkage

Tags: tables, beamer, captions, subfig

I run Arch Linux with texlive version 2019.52579-1. When I compile the LaTeX (Beamer) code below the table caption is "Figure: A simple table." That is, it includes "Figure:" instead of "Table:". The problem does not occur when the subfig package is not used or when the deprecated subfigure package is used instead. Suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A simple frame}

\begin{table} 
\caption{A simple table.}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
a & b \\
c & d \\        
\hline                 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like a recently introduced bug or incompatibility in texlive. It works correctly in my much older version (texlive 2017).

Comment: Found it: [It's a recent bug in the `caption` package](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/66), which is used by `subfig`. According to the link, you can find a fixed version of the package on CTAN, and it should soon be available in TeXLive nad MikTeX (or maybe already is).

Comment: Duplicate: [Table caption starts with Figure after using the caption package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517287/table-caption-starts-with-figure-after-using-the-caption-package)